# Can an alliance from another kingdom help you?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

I am wondering if a friends alliance can come from his kingdom to mine to help my alliance (we are getting demolished by a very powerful alliance and could use help deflecting the attention to regain strength). Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on all the research I've done, it looks like the only way to change kingdoms would be to use a beginner's teleport. This would also need to be used before attaining a level 6 stronghold.  Once you pass that level you are officially stuck in the kingdom you are in. I think you only get 2 beginners teleport's so you also can't move around indefinitely.